# Tomcat 9 not serving my static content from Spring STS 4

Tags: spring, web-applications, tomcat9

Im trying to deploy my web app into tomcat 9. I am using Spring Boot, and Spring STS 4 as IDE.

My app works fine in Spring STS, runs and fetches the static content all fine.

However, when I create a WAR file and deploy it in Tomcat 9, I can't fetch the static files. I get the 404 not found error.

I am using Tomcat default conf and haven't changed anything related to static files in Spring STS.
I don't have @EnableWebMvc anywhere.

Here below my web app structure in Spring STS.

[image: my web app structure in Spring STS]

And in Tomcat

[image]

I have tried accessing the resources on several URL path like:

`/static/images/`

`/images/`

But nothing works.

I am desperate. Can you please help me?

Comment: Care to share the version of Spring Boot you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I am using version 2.7.4

Comment: Did you follow the guide on how to use Spring Boot for a deployable artifact like a war file?

Comment: @M.Deinum I did follow this guide: https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-09/springboot-tomcat/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: If you follow that guide it won't work, as that guide is wrong. Follow [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.9/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment). You need the `configure` method, which isn't part of the guide you are following, basically bootstrapping nothing.